# How do i write update number of download bought function in controller of magento

Tags: sql, magento

i want to update number_of_download_bougt. So How will SQL be in a controllers?
i wrote:

```
public function updatedownloadAction($db_magento, $id, $numberdownload)
{
 // $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', 0);
    $db_magento = Mage::getModel('downloadable/link_purchased_item')->load($id);
    $db_magento->query("UPDATE downloadable_link_purchased_item d
                        SET     d.number_of_downloads_bought = '$numberdownload'
                        WHERE d.item_id = '$id'");
}
```

but it's error

Answer (score 0):

Use the setNumberOfDownloadsUsed function to set the number purchased.

```
$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', 0);
$linkPurchasedItem = Mage::getModel('downloadable/link_purchased_item')->load($id, 'link_hash');
$linkPurchasedItem->setNumberOfDownloadsUsed($linkPurchasedItem->getNumberOfDownloadsUsed()+1);
if ($linkPurchasedItem->getNumberOfDownloadsBought() != 0 && 
  !($linkPurchasedItem->getNumberOfDownloadsBought() - $linkPurchasedItem->getNumberOfDownloadsUsed())) {
  $linkPurchasedItem->setStatus(Mage_Downloadable_Model_Link_Purchased_Item::LINK_STATUS_EXPIRED);
}
$linkPurchasedItem->save();
```

Comment: This code also sets the link to expired if they have bought their full allotment. The code above was in the linkAction() function in the DownloadController.